# SQL Server: Transform arrays of JSON objects into table format

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Following is the given JSON data:

```
DECLARE @Jdata NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'{
  "EmployeeDetails": {
    "BusinessEntityID": 3,
    "NationalIDNumber": 509647174,
    "JobTitle": "Engineering Manager",
    "BirthDate": "1974-11-12",
    "MaritalStatus": "M",
    "Gender": "M",
    "StoreDetail": {
      "Store": [
        {
          "AnnualSales": 800000,
          "AnnualRevenue": 80000,
          "BankName": "Guardian Bank",
          "BusinessType": "BM",
          "YearOpened": 1987,
          "Specialty": "Touring",
          "SquareFeet": 21000
        },
        {
          "AnnualSales": 300000,
          "AnnualRevenue": 30000,
          "BankName": "International Bank",
          "BusinessType": "BM",
          "YearOpened": 1982,
          "Specialty": "Road",
          "SquareFeet": 9000
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}';
```

Need to display:

```
BusinessEntityID |  AnnualSales  |  BusinessType 
-------------------------------------------------
3                   300000          BM
3                   800000          BM
```

My try:

```
select *
from OPENJSON(@jdata)
WITH( 
BusinessEntityID VARCHAR(20) '$.EmployeeDetails.BusinessEntityID',
AnnualSales integer '$.EmployeeDetails.StoreDetail.Store.AnnualSales',
BusinessType VARCHAR(100) '$.EmployeeDetails.StoreDetail.Store.BusinessType'
) as a
```

But getting wrong output.

```
BusinessEntityID |  AnnualSales  |  BusinessType 
-------------------------------------------------
3                   NULL            NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional `OPENJSON()` call and an `APPLY` operator to parse the nested JSON content. In this case you need to use the `AS JSON` modifier in the `WITH` clause to specify that the referenced property (`$.EmployeeDetails.StoreDetail.Store`) contains an inner JSON array.

```
SELECT j1.BusinessEntityID, j2.AnnualSales, j2.BusinessType
FROM OPENJSON(@jdata) WITH ( 
   BusinessEntityID VARCHAR(20) '$.EmployeeDetails.BusinessEntityID',
   Store NVARCHAR(max) '$.EmployeeDetails.StoreDetail.Store' AS JSON
) j1
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(j1.Store) WITH (
  AnnualSales integer '$.AnnualSales',
  BusinessType VARCHAR(100) '$.BusinessType'
) j2
```

Of course, a combination of `JSON_VALUE()` and one `OPENJSON()` call is also an option:

```
SELECT 
  JSON_VALUE(@jdata, '$.EmployeeDetails.BusinessEntityID') AS BusinessEntityID, 
  AnnualSales,
  BusinessType
FROM OPENJSON(@jdata, '$.EmployeeDetails.StoreDetail.Store') WITH (
  AnnualSales integer '$.AnnualSales',
  BusinessType VARCHAR(100) '$.BusinessType'
) j
```

Answer (score 2):

You need two levels of `OPENJSON`. The first one needs to retrieve the inner array using `AS JSON`. Then you feed that into the next using `CROSS APPLY`.

You can also put the `'$.EmployeeDetails'` path into the `OPENJSON` call itself to avoid having to repeat it

```sql
SELECT
  emp.BusinessEntityID,
  store.*
FROM OPENJSON(@Jdata, '$.EmployeeDetails')
  WITH ( 
    BusinessEntityID varchar(20),
    Store nvarchar(max) '$.StoreDetail.Store' AS JSON
  ) AS emp
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(emp.Store)
  WITH (
    AnnualSales integer,
    BusinessType varchar(100)
  ) AS store;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/00CQ46V-)